# React state variable not accurate after set state in useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React function component running along side a legacy JQuery application. When calling an event handler on a JQuery element, passing in the current React state defaults to the initial state value and not the updated state value.

Verified x state is changing through a useEffect hook, but when calling the event listener, x is set to the initial state value and not the state value after the update.

```
function MyComponent(props) {
   const [x, setX] = useState(false);

// On initial render
useEffect(() => {
   props.jQueryButton.addEventListener('click', onXSave)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("x changed " + x); // everytime onXChange is called, x 
    state is updated with the checked value, and this console.log shows 
    the correct state value
}, [x]);

onXChange = event => {
   setX(event.target.checked); // checked is true in this context
};

onXSave = event => {
  const obj = { x: x}; // x is false here, even though the state in this context shows it to be true.
  };
}
```

No error messages are displayed. In the above code in this context I expect the x state to be true in the onXSave method call, but it keeps displaying as false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of `onXSave` that you're adding to your `eventListener` is out of date - you only add it once on the first render, so when `x` updates and causes a re-render, your useEffect doesn't run again and your `jQueryButton` will still holding on to the original function, which has closed over an out of date version of `x`.

You need to do two things:

1. Add `onXSave` and your `jQueryButton` as dependencies in your `useEffect` dependency array (so when it re-renders, the current version of your function is hooked up to your eventListener)
2. Remove the old event listener on re-renders by returning a clean-up function from your `useEffect`.

So something like:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
   const [x, setX] = useState(false);

// On initial render
useEffect(() => {
   props.jQueryButton.addEventListener('click', onXSave)
   return ()=> props.jQueryButton.removeEventListener('click', onXSave)
}, [onXSave, props.jQueryButton])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("x changed " + x); // everytime onXChange is called, x 
    state is updated with the checked value, and this console.log shows 
    the correct state value
}, [x]);

onXChange = event => {
   setX(event.target.checked); // checked is true in this context
};

onXSave = event => {
  const obj = { x: x}; // x is false here, even though the state in this context shows it to be true.
  };


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onXSave` is added as a handler on initial render so `x` has the value from that time. It doesn't matter that `onXSave` is recreated on each render since it's never used past initial render.

To fix this you might put `x` into a `ref`

```js
unction MyComponent(props) {
   const [x, setX] = useState(false);
   const ref = useRef();
   ref.current = x;

// On initial render
useEffect(() => {
   props.jQueryButton.addEventListener('click', onXSave)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("x changed " + x); // everytime onXChange is called, x 
    state is updated with the checked value, and this console.log shows 
    the correct state value
}, [x]);

onXChange = event => {
   setX(event.target.checked); // checked is true in this context
};

onXSave = event => {
  const obj = { x: ref.current}; // by using ref, the value is always current
  };
}
```

Comment: So the correct method is everytime x state's change to add a new eventListener to the button in the useEffect that has a dependency on x?

Comment: @Matt you can use `ref`

Comment: It does matter, because it has closed over the original value of x